# How to make an image width the same as the screen width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make my school project's website mobile-friendly, but I don't want the user to scroll left or right to see images. I want the value of max-width of an image to be the same as the width of the users screen. (When on mobile)

CSS

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}


header{
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 519px;
  height: 200px;
}

header img{
  width: 519px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

HTML

```
<header>
    <h1 class="hidden">Welcome to caillou.tk!</h1>
    <a href="/"><img src="img/k.png" alt="Caillou Logo"></a>

  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4yQCVlLhTmOqX5kUkAGr0g">Watch</a></li>
      <li><a href="characters">Characters</a></li>
      <li><a href="about">About Caillou</a></li>
      <li><a href="credits">Credits</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Yes its a website about Caillou, I have too for a school project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using the percentage attribute in a css class, like:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

if it's only on mobile devices you could make use of the media query:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
   img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

Edit: based on new code and with a random image to represent.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}


header{
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

header img{
  display:flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1 class="hidden">Welcome to caillou.tk!</h1>
    <a href="/"><img src="https://www.intz.com.br/wp-content/uploads/wallpapers/WallpaperLiquifyUltraWide.png" alt="Caillou Logo"></a>

  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4yQCVlLhTmOqX5kUkAGr0g">Watch</a></li>
      <li><a href="characters">Characters</a></li>
      <li><a href="about">About Caillou</a></li>
      <li><a href="credits">Credits</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: I did this put it still goes off mobile phone screens

Comment: did the  ( min-width: 100vw;  min-height: 100vh; ) worked in your case? if it did use the media query and when it's bellow 992px screen width it will resize the image.

Comment: None of the answers here worked

Comment: can you give a bit more info, like a bit of code edited in the main question, maybe in your case it needs a diferent approach from those answered.

Comment: I just added my code to it

Comment: found the issue, header is static with 519px, its not the image itself, i will update the code in a sec.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a background image, you can use this CSS:

```
#image {
    min-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The overflow will be cut off so that the user isn't able to scroll.
(Assuming `image` is the id of your image)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
img {
  width: 100vw;
}
```